# How to set up the condition in markup?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET page that conatins repeater control with another repeater control inside it:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="GroupList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="groupSepatator">
        </div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="ActionList" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="actionData">
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ActionDate").ToString() == "01.01.1980 0:00:00" %>'>
                        <time class="actionDate" datetime="<%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 11) %>">
                            <%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 8) + Eval("StrEndDate") %>
                        </time>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ActionDate").ToString() != "01.01.1980 0:00:00" %>'>
                        <time class="actionDate" itemprop="startDate" datetime="<%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 11) %>">
                            <%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 8) + Eval("StrEndDate") %>
                        </time>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see, there are 2 place holders that form one logical block. I need to add new logical block with 2 similar place holders below the first one inside inner repeater. There should be the condition that depends on query string parameter - ActionTopTypeID. If ActionTopTypeID exists the first block with 2 place holders should be read (visible), and if ActionTopTypeID doesn't exist, the second block with 2 place holders should be read (visible).

There is a condition in code behind as well:

```
if (actionTopTypeID == -1)
{
    items = Method1();
}
else
{
    items = Method2();
}
```

How can I set up the condition in markup?

UPDATED CODE:

```
<div class="actionData" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ActionTopTypeID"]) %>'>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ActionDate").ToString() == "01.01.1980 0:00:00" %>'>
        <time class="actionDate" datetime="<%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 11) %>">
            <%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 8) + Eval("StrEndDate") %>
        </time>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("ActionDate").ToString() != "01.01.1980 0:00:00" %>'>
        <time class="actionDate" itemprop="startDate" datetime="<%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 11) %>">
            <%# Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 8) + Eval("StrEndDate") %>
        </time>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <a class="actionTitle" href="Details.aspx?ActionID=<%# Eval("ActionID") %>" itemprop="url"><div itemprop="name"><%# Eval("NameForH1") %></div></a>
    <a class="actionExtraData" href="Actions.aspx?ActionTypeID=<%# Eval("ActionTypeID") %>"><%# Eval("ActionType") %></a>
    <a class="actionExtraData" href="Actions.aspx?ActionPlaceID=<%# Eval("ActionPlaceID") %>" title="<%# Eval("Coordinates") %>" itemprop="url">
        <span itemprop="location"><%# Eval("PlaceName") %></span>
    </a>
    <a class="linkBuyTicket" href="Order.aspx?ActionID=<%# Eval("ActionID") %>&ActionDate=<%# HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Formatter.FormatDate(Eval("ActionDate").ToString(), 6)) %>">
        <div class="buttonCommonSmall">Заказать билеты</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="actionData" Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ActionTopTypeID"]) %>'>
    Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already applied similar logic to the visibility of your placeholders. Now you can  apply the same to the div wrapping them:

```
<div class="actionData" runat="server"
     Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ActionTopTypeID"]) %>'>
</div>
<div class="actionData" runat="server"
     Visible='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ActionTopTypeID"]) %>'>
</div>
```

Notice that visibility condition is exclusive, and that makes sure that only one of div's is shown at a time.

To make it a bit cleaner you can always introduce a non-private method containing logic in code behind and returning boolean, and then call it like this:

```
<div class="actionData" runat="server"
     Visible='<%# HasActionTopTypeID() %>'>
</div>
<div class="actionData" runat="server"
     Visible='<%# !HasActionTopTypeID() %>'>
</div>
```

Comment: It shows both logical blocks now, but I need only one. Please, take a look at UPDATED CODE above.

Comment: @tesicg, you forgot to add `runat="server"` to the divs. `Visible` attribute only exists on server-side controls

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code sections in ASP:Panel controls and add additional logic to your existing code;

```
if (actionTopTypeID == -1)
{
    items = Method1();
    pnlItems1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    items = Method2();
    pnlItems2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: The panel controls are not visible from code behind because they are inside 2 repeaters.